Next JS router.push not working without page reload
I'm using Next.js 14.2 with the page directory. When I create a build and run npm start, it opens a landing page with a login button using the <Link> component. I also set prefetch={false} in the login button. When I redirect to the login screen and enter all the correct values, it shows "login successful," but it does not redirect to the dashboard. I'm sharing the redirect code below.
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
const router = useRouter();

useEffect(() => {
   if (loggedin && localStorage?.getItem('token')) {
     console.log("isReady", router.isReady);
     router.push(ROUTE_NAMES.DASHBOARD);
   }
 }, [loggedin]);

When I check the console, isReady is returning true. Let me know where I'm wrong.
EDIT
I change a bit and put a condition of isReady state when changing the route. But when i set the middleware I got stuck again it is not changing page.
  if (NO_AUTH_ROUTES.includes(pathname)) {
    return NextResponse.next();
  } else if (isAuthenticate && AUTH_ROUTES.includes(pathname)) {
    // Return to dashboard as it is in auth route
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(ROUTE_NAMES.DASHBOARD, request.url));
  } else if (!AUTH_ROUTES.includes(pathname)) {
    // Check if the pathname is not in AUTH_ROUTES
    // If token or isAuthenticate is missing, redirect to login
    if (!isAuthenticate) {
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(ROUTE_NAMES.LOGIN, request.url));
    }
  }
  return NextResponse.next();

Solution: github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/51782

You might encounter an issue where router.push() in Next.js doesn't redirect the user as expected after successful authentication when called from middleware. A potential fix for this is to refresh the router just before invoking router.push(). This seems to solve the issue, though the exact reason behind it isn't well-documented.
Here’s a code example:


// After successful authentication
router.refresh(); // Refresh the router state
router.push('/desired-url'); // Redirect the user to the desired URL



By calling router.refresh(), you force the router to update its state, which ensures that router.push() works as intended. This approach worked for me, and I hope it helps others facing the same issue.
Reference: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/51782#discussioncomment-6470680

The router.push() function is being called before the router instance is ready. router.isReady is true only when the router is completely ready.
Add a condition check if the router is ready before performing the redirect:
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

useEffect(() => {
    if (loggedin && localStorage?.getItem('token')) {
        if (router.isReady) {
            router.push(ROUTE_NAMES.DASHBOARD);
        }
    }
}, [loggedin, router.isReady]);


If I set the middleware, it is not working.
 if (NO_AUTH_ROUTES.includes(pathname)) {
    return NextResponse.next();
  } else if (isAuthenticate && AUTH_ROUTES.includes(pathname)) {
    // Return to dashboard as it is in auth route
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(ROUTE_NAMES.DASHBOARD, request.url));
  } else if (!AUTH_ROUTES.includes(pathname)) {
    // Check if the pathname is not in AUTH_ROUTES
    // If token or isAuthenticate is missing, redirect to login
    if (!isAuthenticate) {
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(ROUTE_NAMES.LOGIN));
    }
  }


@HGWebs The isAuthenticate variable might not be correctly set. The NO_AUTH_ROUTES and AUTH_ROUTES arrays might not include all the routes they should. The pathname variable might not be correctly set. The NextResponse.redirect and NextResponse.next methods might not be working as expected. Check if these methods are correctly implemented and used. In this case the setup is correct, the issue you have is local. If you ask another question and tag me with more context and I'll try to solve it. And mark it as correct if it is, please.

All these method are working correctly if i run the npm run dev all things are perfectly working but only if i run the production build this issue occur.

@HGWebs Most likely there is some issue with your PRO build.

Thanks for help but i got the solution
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/51782
